# R/ggplot2: use literal strings on parse()

Tags: r, parsing, ggplot2, expression

Can part of the string I pass to `parse(text=...)` be taken as a literal string? Literal string means it will not try to interpret it.

For instance, I want to have the text "*p*-value" text in a plot (with the p italicized).

I am doing:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(500)), aes(x)) + geom_histogram() + geom_text(label='italic(p)-value==0.10', parse=TRUE, x=-2, y=40)
```

Result:

[image: pvalue]

The hyphen has a little too much padding and too big (because it takes it as the subtraction symbol), and it is not showing the number with the full precision I have used.

Can I just tell him to take part of that string as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(500)), aes(x)) + 
    geom_histogram() + 
    annotate("text", label='italic(p)*"-value"=="0.15"', parse=TRUE, x=-2, y=40)
```

Here we use double quotes to specify character values and use `*` to place them right next to expressions.

Also note the change to `annotate()` rather than `geom_text()`. The latter would print out a 500 labels at the same location since it's tied to the data you specified in the `ggplot` call.

With `set.seed(15)`, I get

[image]

Comment: I did not know you could use "-quotes within '-quotes. This is great! Thank you!